# what is the meaning of pip install -v?

Tags: pip

Recently, I seen a command of `pip install -v`

actually it is

```
$ git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex
$ cd apex
$ pip install -v --no-cache-dir --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext" ./
```

I usually command `pip install something`

But what is `pip install -v`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> -v or we can can also use --verbose. Both are same.

> -v is used when you want to use or expressed something in more words than are needed.

> -v Give more output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times.